# Laravel Validation - How to check if a value exists in a given array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, laravel, laravel-5

So, okay i tried a lot of rules from validation docs but all give me same error saying

> Array to string conversion

Here is how I add the array:

```
$this->validate($request,[
                'employee' => 'required|in:'.$employee->pluck('id')->toArray(),
            ],[
                'employee.in' => 'employee does not exists',
            ]);
```

Any hint on how to achieve this?

**i created a custom validator** but still passing array seems to be not possible

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Implode the array as a string and join it on commas.

```
'employee' => 'required|in:'.$employee->implode('id', ', '),
```

This will make the correct comma separated string that the validator expects when making an `in` comparison.

**Edit**

This still works, but is not the *Laravelesque* way of doing it anymore. See the answer by @nielsiano.

Answer (score 33):

You are now able to use the `Rule` class instead of imploding values yourself as described in the correct answer. Simply do:

```php
$ids = $employee->pluck('id')->toArray();
['employee' => ['required', Rule::in($ids)]];
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-in) for the "in" rule.

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach. Here the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in) to its documentation in laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be accomplished in for ways**

1. You can do like this you need to user **use Illuminate\Validation\Rule** class top of your script

   ```
   $request->validate ([
        'someProperty' => [
            'required',
             Rule::in(['manager', 'delivery_boy', 'stuff'])
        ]
   ]);
   ```
2. You can also do like this in: required a string like **'required|in:manager, delivery_boy, stuff'**

   > "required|in:" . implode(", ",$rules)

   ```
   $rules = ['manager', 'delivery_boy', 'stuff'];
   $request->validate([
       'someProperty' => "required|in:" . implode(", ",$rules)
   ]);
   ```
3. This way will work when you're using **Validator** class

   ```
   \Validator::make($request->all(),[
           'someProperty' => [
               'required',
               Rule::in(['manager', 'delivery_boy', 'stuff'])
           ]
       ])
   ```
4. When you use Laravel form request class for validation request

   ```php
   public function rules(): array
   {
       return [
           'someProperty' => [
               'required',
               Rule::in(['manager', 'delivery_boy', 'stuff'])
           ]
       ];
   }


   public function authorize(): bool
   {
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Is this really just a copy of the other two answers into a single post?  Do researchers need to see the same solutions ...again?

Comment: this is not copy paste I think this will help for developer to know multiple way to implement

Comment: But you are just re-providing the same techniques that were already provided by the 2 earlier answers, right?