# Require a field if the value exists in another field, which is an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Say a model has a status property, that holds an array of strings. If this array contains a string name "Other", the `status_other` field should be required. I can achieve this with the following rules:

```
'status' => 'nullable|array',
'status_other' => Rule::requiredIf(in_array('Other', $this->model->status))
```

Is there a way to write the status_other rule as a string? I tried:

```
'status_other' => 'required_if:status,in:Other',
```

and

```
'status_other' => 'required_if:status,Other',
```

Both that did not work.

Comment: Something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413073/laravel-validation-how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-given-array/36413348) could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare it by using `'=='` to match the string in the array.

```
'status_other' => 'required_if:status,==,Other',
```

Comment: How does `==` check if "Other" is inside "status" array? Just tried your suggestion without success.