# Laravel 10x: Form Requests check if value exists in array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code that checks if the value is contained within the array:

```
$allowedPeoples = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 12);

if(!in_array($data['number_select'], self::$allowedNumbers) ){
    return response()->json(['errors' => true, 'message' => 'Error in AllowedNumbers'], 422);
}
```

As I'm using Laravel, I have to avoid doing validations the old fashioned way, I'd like to convert this code into a **Form Request rule**:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'number_selected' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

How I can do this?

Comment: You probably want the [`in` rule](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-in)

Comment: @anynber it works like a charm, but failed when we have text (string) in ```$allowedNumbers = array('foo', 'bar', 'liks')```. How can I solve this?

Comment: It should work with either numbers or letters. Can you post the full rules you're trying, and what is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Validation - How to check if a value exists in a given array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413073/laravel-validation-how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-given-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try `in` to validate within array

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'number_selected' => 'required|in:' . implode(',', $yourArray)
    ];
}
```

Comment: And if I have this array of string?: ```$allowedNumbers = array('foo', 'bar', 'liks')``` ?

Comment: @SudoSur you want  to accept only numbers ? and throw an error when there is string in array?

Comment: I have another validation that checks if the selected options is 'foo', 'bar' or 'links'.